# Запрос по протоколу SOAP

Tags: xml, веб-программирование, c, soap, c++

Здравствуйте. Возможно кто-то направит меня в гугл или еще куда, но скажу сразу, что ничего путного я там не нашел, да и для хэш кода будет полезно хранить такой ответ. Мне нужно отправить SOAP запрос на веб-сервис, перерыл кучу инфы, уже неделю с этим вожусь, дали задание на практике, а я максимум с сетью, что делал, так это с vk api работал. Я пробовал работать с такими вещами как:

- Libcurl - все описания на него
     старые, ссылки битые, к проекту не
     прикрутить (Visual Studio).
- gSOAP - аналогично, на первых же
     этапах не получается, даже из статьи 
     с хабра, появляются ошибки на 1 этапе.

Подскажите или покажите, как реализовать самый простой SOAP запрос на C/C++, желательно при использовании минимума заголовочных файлов и библиотек. Или если с их использованием, то пожалуйста дайте ссылку на статью где ссылки не битые и описано по человечески без ошибок.

Comment: Тебе адрес до WSDL выдали?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант напрямую слать через сокеты HTTP пакет с SOAP запросом.
Но лучше работать с gSOAP

Здесь есть конкретные примеры, которые должны работать.
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Comment: я постараюсь по вашей ссылке сделать, в скором времени напишу, что получится

Comment: не получается вообще